# De-duplicating similar but not identical URLs with a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, deduplication

I have a dataset with thousands of URLs stored in a column called `Website` (type `VARCHAR`) in a table called `WebsiteData`. There are many pairs of URLs (stored in separate rows) that are identical except that one begins with `www`, e.g. `www.google.com` and the other does not, e.g., `google.com`. How would I design a SQL query that identifies these pseudo-duplicates and deletes the version that does not start with `www`?

Comment: You should know that those aren't necessarily duplicate URLs

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, just because *commonly* `www.someurl.com` directs to `someurl.com` it doesn't means that this is always the case at all

Comment: Fair. For this dataset, I think it is a reasonable enough assumption that I won't be losing any critical information if I make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I derived 2 tables one with urls that have `www.` and one without. Join them together by adding www. to the urls without.

```
-- SELECT first to review the records.
select *
from
(select * from website where url not like 'www.%') wA
join 
(select * from website where url like 'www.%') wB
    on 'www.' + wa.url = wb.url


delete wA
from
(select * from website where url not like 'www.%') wA
join 
(select * from website where url like 'www.%') wB
    on 'www.' + wa.url = wb.url
```

Answer (score 0):

using SUBSTRING to get the website part after first . and matching with any duplicate entry and removing it.

```
DELETE  tableW
FROM tableW W
JOIN 
(
select W1.website
FROM tableW W1
inner join tableW W2
on W1.website = SUBSTRING(W2.website,CHARINDEX('.',W2.website, 0)+1, LEN(w2.website))
) T
on T.website = W.website
```